# Knp menu bundle warnings after update to symfony 2.3

Tags: php, symfony, deprecated, knpmenubundle

After updating symfony from 2.2 to 2.3, i've got new stange errors on all my pages and in my scripts:

*Deprecated: Knp\Menu\Silex\Voter\RouteVoter is deprecated because of namespace, use Knp\Menu\Matcher\Voter\RouteVoter instead. in \vendor\knplabs\knp-menu\src\Knp\Menu\Silex\Voter\RouteVoter.php on line 20*

and

*Deprecated: Knp\Menu\Silex\RoutingExtension is deprecated, use Knp\Menu\Integration\Symfony\RoutingExtension instead. in \vendor\knplabs\knp-menu\src\Knp\Menu\Silex\RoutingExtension.php on line 15*

How could I fix this ? I don't find the answer on the web.
Thank you in advance

Here is my composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "genemu/form-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/gaufrette": "0.2.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle":          "dev-master",
    "jms/serializer-bundle":                 "0.13.*@dev",
        "amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php":     "dev-master",
        "punkave/symfony2-file-uploader-bundle": "dev-master",
        "oneup/uploader-bundle":                 "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle":          "dev-master",
        "jms/debugging-bundle":                  "dev-master",
        "winzou/console-bundle":                 "dev-master",
        "elao/web-profiler-extra-bundle" :       "dev-master",
        "cybernox/amazon-webservices-bundle":    ">=1.5.4",
        "genemu/form-bundle":                    "2.2.*",
    "escapestudios/wsse-authentication-bundle": "2.3.x-dev",
        "rezzza/flickr-bundle":                  "1.0.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":               "dev-master",
        "genemu/form-bundle":                    "2.1.*",
        "leaseweb/api-caller-bundle":        "*",
        "eo/honeypot-bundle":                    "dev-master"        
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }, 
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

and my menu builder:

```
namespace ...\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\Matcher\Matcher;
use Knp\Menu\MenuFactory;
use Knp\Menu\Renderer\ListRenderer;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class Builder extends ContainerAware
{
    public function mainMenu(MenuFactory $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

        $menu->addChild('Dashboard', array(
                        'route' => 'dashboard' )); 
        $menu->addChild('Color Scheme', array(
                        'uri' => 'slidescheme' ));
        $menu->addChild('Questionnnaires', array(
                        'uri' => 'questionnaire_manage' ));
        // ... add more children

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a dev version of knplabs/menu. Edit your composer file from:

```
"knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":               "dev-master",
```

to:

```
"knplabs/knp-menu-bundle" :               "~1.1",
```

and the error message will go away.  Note that if you're actually *using* dev features of knplabs/menu (like `Matcher` and `Voter`) those won't be available any more. But Symfony does not require them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea update your symfony version in the middle of a develpment. Actually, it's a bad idea upgrade any bundle you are using in your code (there's always exceptions, but this is the general rule).

In your case, the bundle has been refactored in this new version, so now it's not compatible with the code you have written . I'm afraid you only have two alternatives:

- Adapt your code to the new requirements
- **Or** change your composer again to use symfony 2.2 and run **composer update**

I strongly suggest the second option if you already have many lines of code written.

Comment: Thank you victor, in fact I would update to the LTS version.
I not the advice and will never update again. 
So the solution is to refactor my code wich is using that bundle.